# Rx Observable Window with closing function with parameter

Tags: system.reactive

I'm trying to separate observable into windows (or for my purposes also Buffers are fine) while being able to close windows/buffers at custom location.

E.g. I have an observable which produces integers starting at 1 and moving up. I want to close a window at each number which is divisible by 7. My closing function would need to take in the item as parameter in that case.

There is an overload of `Window` method:

```
Window<TSource, TWindowClosing>(IObservable<TSource>, Func<IObservable<TWindowClosing>>)
```

Either it cant be done using this overload, or I can't wrap my head around it. [Documentation describes that it does exactly what I want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229909%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) but does not show an example. Also, it shows an example of non-deterministic closing, which depends on timing when closing observable collection emits items.

> The Window operator breaks up an observable sequence into consecutive
>   non-overlapping windows. The end of the current window and start of
>   the next window is controlled by an observable sequence which is the
>   result of the windowClosingSelect function which is passed as an input
>   parameter to the operator. The operator could be used to group a set
>   of events into a window. For example, states of a transaction could be
>   the main sequence being observed. Those states could include:
>   Preparing, Prepared, Active, and Committed/Aborted. The main sequence
>   could include all of those states are they occur in that order. The
>   windowClosingSelect function could return an observable sequence that
>   only produces a value on the Committed or Abort states. This would
>   close the window that represented transaction events for a particular
>   transaction.

I'm thinking something like following would do the job, but I'd have to implement it myself:

```
Window<TSource, TWindowClosing>(IObservable<TSource>, Func<TSource, bool>)
```

- Is such windowing possible with built-in functions (I know I can build one myself)?
- Is it possible to close a window based on emitted item or only non-deterministically, once an item is emitted from windowing observable?

Comment: For those having same problem wrapping their head around this, I suggest to read [about hot and cold observables](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the original sequence with a `Where` clause as your closing sequence.  If your source sequence is cold, then make use of `Publish` and `RefCount` to make it work correctly.

```
var source = ...;
var sharedSource = source.Publish().RefCount();
var closingSignal = sharedSource.Where(i => (i % 7) == 0);
var windows = sharedSource.Window(() => closingSignal);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried it out and saw it works, but I have a followup question if you care enough :) Does window with closing function work by counting how many times closing function iterated before emitting an item? Also, what I've tried worked without `RefCount` so thank you for mentioning it. You probably saved me some time in future debugging.

Comment: no, `Window` starts by calling the closing function to get a signal.  It then subscribes to the observable that was returned.  Whenever that observable produces a value (any value will do), it unsubscribes from the observable, closes the window, starts a new window, calls the closing function to get a new observable and subscribes to it.  So it merely calls the closing function when it needs a new signal.

Comment: @NikolaRadosavljević [RefCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211664(v=vs.103).aspx) isn't required.  It has very specific behavior of which you should be aware before using it.  Sometimes calling [Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211748(v=vs.103).aspx) after setting up all of your subscriptions is the better choice.